# Getting incorrect query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am passing variable value as `$id="'10','11',12'"` from view to model through controller, when I fetch the records from mysql table using above `$id` value as:

```
$query=$this->db->query('select * from userdetails where Id IN ($ids)')
```

I am not getting results, but it prints the query as:

```
SELECT * FROM (`userdetails`) WHERE `Id` IN ('\'10\',\'11\',\'12\'')
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Also try printing the Query and value of the query.Or show us more details of your code.

Comment: why you are getting quotes for ids...are those ids strings...try with implode one which is said by Bhuvan Rikka......I am also using same like that in my application......

Comment: can't you pass the values as `$id="10,11,12"`?? Any specific reason to pass them as a string?

Comment: @lalith Please more one of the answer as accepted if it fixed problem.

Answer (score 4):

**Ok Try this :**

```
$this->db->escape($id);
$query=$this->db->query("select * from userdetails where Id IN ($ids)");
```

Use   `stripslashes($id);`  before passing in the query. Or  `mysql_real_escape_string()` should also work.
In this way :

```
$ids = stripslashes($ids);
$query=$this->db->query("select * from userdetails where Id IN ($ids)");
```

Or you can send the value in comma separated in this way $ids = "11,12,13";
and it should work.

Comment: Btw $this->db->query may not be working as you are using single quote.

Comment: this is working, but when we write the query as 
$this->db->select('*')->from('userdetails')->where_in('Id',$ids);
$query=$this->db->get();
it is not working, getting query as 
SELECT * FROM (`userdetails`) WHERE `Id` IN ('\'10\',\'11\',\'12\'')

Answer (score 2):

Send the ids in an array...

```
$id_array = array('10','11','12');
```

Model:

```
//implode converts your array into a string without quotes
$comma_separated = implode(",",$id_array);
$query=$this->db->query('select * from userdetails where Id IN ($comma_separated)');
```